# verifing some arguments in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm doing a verification in BASH

```
if [ !( ( -e $f ) || ($# -lt 2) || ( -d $f ) ) ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

I'm trying to see if the file existes or if it's a directory or enough args are passed via terminal. Can I do this or must it be done in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather from your question you want to reject anything that is not an ordinary file. In that case, the test for a directory is redundant if you use -f instead of -e.

```
if [[  ! -f "$f" || $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

By the way, if this is an error exit, you should exit with something other than 0 - 0 indicates success in most cases; exit 1 would be better.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have at least a few problems here.

- The syntax for your test will require the more modern double `[[` command instead of the legacy single `[` command.
- You're missing a `fi` at the end. (I edited this one in for you, with thanks to whoever modded it up.)
- You *may* have the sense of your test reversed, but I'm not sure. It depends on what the rest of your script looks like.